# Pub/Sub Topic to BigQuery Table Subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

**Pub/Sub topic schema**

```
syntax = "proto3";

message UserProfile {
    string name= 1;
    string phone= 2;
    map<string, string> address= 3;
}
```

**Topic data**

```
{"name":"name","phone":"phone","address":{"streetname":"streetnamee","zipcode":"000000"}}
```

This would be consumed by a Big Query Subscription "Write To BigQuery"

I have selected :

1. Use Topic Schema
2. Drop Unknown fields

**Unable to process the address data to the bq table, having tried 2 datatypes ARRAY and JSON**

Big Query Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `dataset.tablename`
(
  name STRING OPTIONS(description=""),
  phone STRING OPTIONS(description=""),
  address ARRAY<STRUCT<a STRING, b STRING>>
)
```

**or**

```
    CREATE TABLE `dataset.tablename`
    (
      name STRING OPTIONS(description=""),
      phone STRING OPTIONS(description=""),
      address JSON
    );
```

**when commented the address field its working**

Comment: Have you tried with actual field names in Struct instead of a and b? i.e. streetname and zipcode

Comment: For few inserts there would be more than the two fields in the address,  example some might have 'city', 'state' etc.  The address field was declared as repeated key-value pairs a, b.

Comment: Got it, as per https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubtobigquery Map corresponds to Bigquery Array<KeyType, ValueType> which I assume is ARRAY<STRUCT<KeyType, ValueType>>. Have you tried giving unnamed fields? i.e. ARRAY<STRUCT<String, String>>

Comment: right, un-naming the fields arises bq complication error  "Illegal field name:"   example : address ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRING>>

Answer (score 2):

For Cloud Pub/Sub to BigQuery subscriptions with a map type in the schema, you need to have table with an `ARRAY` of a `STRUCT` with fields named `key` and `value`:

```
CREATE TABLE `dataset.tablename`
(
  name STRING,
  phone STRING,
  address ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>
);
```

Comment: Thanks @kamal Abol, able to process the data with your solution, however if I wish to store the nested json 'address' to the address column in bq table as {"streetname":"streetnamee","zipcode":"000000"} in JSON format, how do I parse it ?

Comment: In that case, it doesn't look like your topic schema really matches the data. You'd need to have a nested record type in your schema that has the streetname and zipcode fields instead of the map.